# Sharepoint Content Approval message

Tags: sharepoint

I Have Content Approval turned on for a list. When Users create Items they get the message 'Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights.'

I want to change the text of this message in a particular site collection.

I found the message defined in \12\config\resources\wss.resx with a key of checkin_publishMajordesc.

Does anyone know if there's a way to override the seetiings in the Resources filesat the site collection level, or even at the page level?

The site is currently on wss 2007

Answer (score 0):

The message is from the [ApprovalMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.approvalmessage.aspx) control. It is being used by the [InformationBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.informationbar.aspx) template found in 12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates.ascx:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="InformationBar" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <SharePoint:GenericInformationBar runat="server">
            <Template_Controls>
                <SharePoint:FileUploadedMessage runat="server"/>
                <SharePoint:ApprovalMessage runat="server"/>
                <SharePoint:EmailCalendarMessage runat="server"/>
                <Sharepoint:CopySourceInfo runat="server" />
                <Sharepoint:AssignToEmailMessage runat="server" />
            </Template_Controls>
        </SharePoint:GenericInformationBar>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

You could create your own template to override this behavior. Examples are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544582.aspx), [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2009/11/03/how-to-customize-sharepoint-2007-forms-part-3-field-validations.aspx), and [here](http://ketulpatel.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/removing-attachment-button-from-moss-form-toolbar/).

It takes some effort, but it works. Alternatively, you could use CSS or Javascript/JQuery to hide/change the text inside table.ms-informationbar.