# Where can I find discussion board newform.aspx page to modify?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I have to modify text in discussion board new post page. Now it is showing **"Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. More information on content approval."**

I have to append some text to this message. I am trying to find discussion board newform.aspx page to modify. Please let me know where can I get that?

Comment: Do you want to modify this text or just remove this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your discussion list is called "Public Discussion" at a site called "http://yoursite"

1. Connect to the site (http://yoursite) with sharepoint designer
2. Go to All Files -> Lists -> Public Discussion -> NewForm.aspx
3. Edit file
4. Look for `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">`
5. Add content as needed
6. Save file, it will warn you that you are about to save a customised layout.

The message you describe is injected by sharepoint's content approval framework. To custom the messsage, you will most likely need to use javascript to find the message box and change the text.

On my site the html xpath to the node is something like this:

`//span[@id='part1']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]`

Answer (score 0):

On the file system it will be here:

$sphome / "Name of your discussion board" (this will be a folder) / Forms / newform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356189/sharepoint-content-approval-message).  It describes custom template controls handle the display of this content.

There is also a link [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsocialcomputing/thread/4e0c5e97-10f2-4c36-b756-36bff31feb7c) that describes a solution to do this using css.  This would allow you to hide the OOB text and then have your own content displayed instead.  However, there is some question of it working on broswers other than IE so include this in your testing.